# unwanted characters appended to response . JAVA / AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, api, google-chrome-devtools

I am calling a web service(api) from the client side using angularJS

```
http://localhost:8082/login/api
```

In back end when I am debugging the code to check the response, I am sending response value as `success` (String value)  only. But when I used chrome developer tool to see the response of the above called api, it is coming as

```
7
↵success
↵0
↵
↵
```

I am not able to figure it out where this unwanted characters are getting appended with response string.

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the same result in RestClient?

Comment: currently it is coming as failure

Comment: Can you provide us some client and server side code

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify your response in whatever format you are working on. e.g

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + "<-success);
```